# How can I move the horizon line?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I used world texture to make the sky in my scene, but when I render it, there is a gap from sky to objects in the scene. This is what I mean:
[image: Horizon line]

How can I move down the horizon line? Is there another way to set the sky? Because I want the feel the scene is in a place high in the sky.

I am using Blender internal render.

Comment: What kind of sky/texture is it? A equirectangular panorama? A sphere map? A flat 2D texture?

Comment: It's a sky map image 12.000 x 3.000, from here: http://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/659732

Answer (score 7):

**if you are using cycles:**

In the node editor, add an *input > texture coordinate* node and a *vector > mapping node*.  Plug the *generated* output of the *texture coordinate* node into the *vector* input of the *mapping* node and the *vector* output of the *mapping* node into the *vector* input of the *environment texture* node.  You can then tweak the values on the *mapping* node to move, scale, and rotate the environment texture.

Comment: What about using BI?

Answer (score 6):

Changing the size and position of sky textures in the blender internal is as simple as changing a value.
Go to the *Texture* tab of the *Properties* window. Scroll down to the *Mapping* category, then increase the Y value for the *Offset*.
If you then have a problem of the image missing from the top, you can scale it up with the *Size* values.
[image: texture settings]