# How to lower the horizon using the sky hdrs from 3d wolf

Tags: rendering, hdri

I am using the sky kdrs from 3d wolf but the horizon is too high. On all of my scenes you always see part of the horizon missing. I know with blender guru's hdrs you can change the horizon. So i am wondering if you guys have any idea on how to do this with 3d wolfs free hdrs?

Comment: Here is a link to a picture if you want: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3K91vxB9L_tNnJVMWRVMW1nUHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: again, please don't post images using google drive,use the tools on this site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SIUS.png

Comment: It never seems to work for me. It always says it is trying to upload but it never does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move the horizon line?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18444/15265)